# How to get a component's parent form in Borland VCL?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, vcl

I'd like to determine which form a given component belongs to in my application. Neither the Parent nor the Owner property can be assumed to be the form itself, so I can't simply use this.

I guess I could just go through the Parent property recursively until I arrive at something derived from TForm, but is there a better way to do this? I used the search function, but couldn't find anything specific to my problem.

I'm using Borland C++ Builder, by the way (tagged Delphi because a majority of VCL users seem to write in Delphi, and I read Delphi code just fine).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

You could use `GetParentForm` in `Forms` unit - it's used by the VCL a lot, too. It does what you mentioned - recursively find the first `TCustomForm` in its parents. In addition, it also handles design time.